# Voice Recognition

Tags: testing, voice-recognition

As it was presented in [OMG! Ubuntu!](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2013/02/power-voice-recognition-demoed-for-ubuntu-video) a voice recognition tool is being developed and will possible deploy in Ubuntu Touch and Ubuntu Desktop.

Although beyond the video shared in youtube I had no more information about that, rumors said that a testing ppa would be available for Ubuntu 13.04, although I didn't got anything else about this matter.

So if anyone knows about a testing PPA or any other way to test it share with us.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm one of the lead developers on this project. The voice recognition program that OMG! Ubuntu! showed is not being developed by Canonical. We currently do not have a PPA but you can find the project on [GitHub](https://github.com/JamezQ/Palaver).

We are also occasionally on IRC #speechRecognition

In order to install Linux Speech Recognition go to the [project's GitHub page](https://github.com/JamezQ/Palaver). Download the ZIP file and extract it.

Then install some dependencies:

```
sudo apt-get install sox python-argparse libsox-fmt-mp3 mutt xvkbd xautomation
```

Open the extracted folder (Palaver-master) in the terminal and execute the setup:

```
cd /~Path-to-folder~/Palaver-master/
./setup
```

Now it is just to assign a hotkey to enable recording, in order to do that go to System Settings... > Keyboard > Shortcuts > Custom Shortcuts click the Plus Button to add a shortcut, name it Voice Recognition and set the command to:

```
/~Path-to-folder~/Palaver-master/hotkey
```

Click apply, click over the shortcut and then assign a hotkey to activate Voice Recognition.

Comment: Thanks for that, already installed it and testing, I will try to help if possible in the TO BE DONE BEFORE RELEASE part, but only if I am capable of something haha. Sorry for misunderstanding who is backing the project, will fix that in my question.